# is self keyword necessary in Python Tkinter applications?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code and it seemed to work fine without the "self" being added to the widget instances. Will i run into problems down the line if i don't use the self ?

```
class Appy:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.drawBoard()

    def drawBoard(self):
        pane_1 = ttk.PanedWindow(master, orient='horizontal')
        pane_1.pack(padx=20, pady=10, fill='both', expand=True)

        photo_frame = ttk.Frame()
        content_frame = ttk.Frame()

        pane_1.add(photo_frame)
        pane_1.add(content_frame)

        image_label = ttk.Label(photo_frame)
        image_label.pack(anchor='center', fill='both', expand=True)

        ....



if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tkinter.Tk()
    Appy(master)
    master.geometry('1250x750+200+50')
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self` is not a keyword. It's a *variable name* representing the instance object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding the `self` to the widget instances". Could you show an example?

Comment: Do you want to be able to access that PanedWindow outside the drawBoard method? If so, you should make it an attribute, not a local variable, that is, `self.pane_1 = ttk.PanedWindow(master, orient='horizontal')`

Comment: yes Aran, Thank you, that answers my question